# Cannot access Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, mbr

I am new to Linux and I had Ubuntu installed using some instructions I found on the internet, I got my drive partitioned and once I had it installed, I can't find my Windows 7.

[image: the result of the partition]

Comment: Run `sudo parted -l` and edit results into your question.

Comment: I edited the result in the question

Answer (score 0):

I think you format all drive.
check partition first.

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

share the output

Comment: Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    999423    997376  487M Linux swap
/dev/sda2     999424  30296063  29296640   14G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3   30296064 225607679 195311616 93.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  225607680 225705983     98304   48M EFI System

Comment: <pre>Model: ATA ST320LT020-9YG14 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  512MB   511MB   linux-swap(v1)
 2      512MB   15.5GB  15.0GB  ext4                  legacy_boot
 3      15.5GB  116GB   100GB   ext4
 4      116GB   116GB   50.3MB  fat32                 boot, esp

</pre>